# Why isn't my SQL UNION working?

Tags: sql, database

I have three tables which I'm trying to query to return a single table in this format:

```
Message   Period   Date   Firstname   Lastname   Room_ID   Description
   x         x       x        x          x          x           x
   x         x       x        x          x          x           x
```

Table 'message' has columns Message, Period, Date, Room_ID, Teacher_ID. Table 'rooms' has columns Room_ID, Description. Table 'teachers' has columns Teacher_ID, Firstname, Lastname.

Where am I going wrong with my SQL statement?

```
SELECT Message, Period, Date FROM message
UNION
SELECT * FROM rooms
UNION
SELECT Firstname, Lastname
FROM teacher
RIGHT JOIN message
ON teacher.Teacher_ID=message.Teacher_ID
```

Each SELECT query works great on its own but I'm having trouble combining them.

Comment: All components to a `union` have to have the same columns.

Comment: I see. What would be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` combines *rows* from different tables.  All the subqueries need to have the same columns.

Presumably, you want `join`s:

```
SELECT m.Message, m.Period, m.Date, t.Firstname, t.LastName, r.roomID, r.Description
FROM message m JOIN
     teacher t
     ON t.Teacher_ID = m.Teacher_ID JOIN
     rooms r
     ON m.Room_ID = r.Room_ID;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Gordon.